# How to dynamically generate markers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

So I am trying to use leaflet with angular, I'm fetching data from an API that displays information about every country in the world, and using a foreach loop I managed to get the name of the country and the latitude and the longitude of the country. I want this data because I want to generate custom markers based on the lat and lng of the country, but I'm stuck and I don't know how to go on.

```
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  private map:any;


   tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});


  private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [ 42.245, 15.271],
      zoom:3
    });
  }

  private getLangLng(): void {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(({ name,latlng }) =>
      console.log("name: "+name+" cord:"+latlng)

    );
  });
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
    this.tiles.addTo(this.map);


  }
```

Comment: In which point are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the data to generate the markers

Comment: You said you got the last lng. Then you can create markers. The problem is that if you create for every country on map load the browser will freeze cause there going to be prrobably many markers